# Counting in how many rows a value exists

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to count the frequency of words in a data frame. Here is an example of what i'm trying to achieve.

```
words = ['Dungeon',
'Crawling',
'Puzzle',
'RPG',]

desc = 
0       [Dungeon, count, game, kid, draw, toddler, Unique]
1       [Beautiful, simple, music, application, toddle]
2       [Fun, intuitive, number, game, baby, toddler]
```

Note that desc is a 1690 rows pandas data frame.

Now I would like to check `words[i] in desc`
I do not want to have nested for loop, so  made a function to just check if the word is in the desc and then use `apply()` to each row and then use `sum`.

The function I got is:

```
def tmp(word, desc):
    return (word in desc)
```

However, when I use the following code: `desc.apply(tmp, args = words[0])` I get the error that states: `tmp() takes 2 positional arguments but 8 were given`. However, when I manually use it with values `tmp(words[0], desc[0])` it works just fine....

Comment: `desc.apply(lambda x: tmp(x, words[0]))`, but using `apply` in this case is unecessary and quite slow as well, since it will still iterate over the rows.

Comment: Is your dataframe a single column of python lists? Because in that case you will have to do a linear search over the lists regardless. Perhaps you should consider using a different data structure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If want avoid loops, use DataFrame constructor with [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and for count `True` values use `sum`:

```
s = pd.DataFrame(desc.tolist()).isin(words).sum(axis=1)
print(s)
0    1
1    0
2    0
dtype: int64
```